# Know when Core Data has saved all entities using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsxmlparser

I am using `NSXMLParser` to read a large XML file. Once I get the data element that I want I create an `NSManagedObject` and save that on a background context. The imported file will have `n` number of imported items, it is never known.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [ZSSCoreDataManager sharedService].persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext;
[backgroundContext performBlock:^{

    // Create and insert new entity here
    [self createAndInsertWithDictionary:object];

    // Save
    if ([backgroundContext hasChanges]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![backgroundContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"%@", error);

        }

        // Save was successful, reset to release memory
        [backgroundContext reset];

    }

}];
```

Because parsing can happen faster than a `save:` can complete, how can I know when the XML file is done reading AND all my `Core Data` objects have completed saving? I know of the `parserDidEndDocument:` method, but this doesn't help to know when all of my object have completed saving to `Core Data`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious way would be to replace `performBlock` with `performBlockAndWait`, so that you know once the block has finished that the save has also finished.

If you don't want to wait, this sounds like a job for a dispatch group. That would allow scheduling a function to be called only after a bunch of asynchronous code had finished.

- Create a dispatch group with `dispatch_group_create`
- Every time you start one of these blocks, call `dispatch_group_enter` before doing anything else.
- Every time a save completes, call `dispatch_group_leave`
- Use `dispatch_group_notify` to schedule a block that will only be executed when every "enter" has been matched by a "leave".

Put code in the "notify" block that should run once every save has finished.

Comment: I have used the dispatch group pattern quite a lot, but for this situation I wondered how it would work if `dispatch_group_enter` was called after the xml object was parsed and then saved very quickly before another `dispatch_group_enter` was created. Therefore the `dispatch_group_notify` could be called. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Just tested this, and it does trigger the `dispatch_group_notify` right away. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah-- add an "enter" before you begin the process. Add a "leave" in `parserDidEndDocument`. Then you can't call the notify block before the parser finishes.